# Short story with evil supercomputer/AI probably based in Xanadu

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

That is almost everything I remember about it.

It was really short, probably old too. The early portion of the story describes the land and compares it to Xanadu, with fountains and stuff. The later part describes an evil AI/Supercomputer. There was something about the protagonist finding a port which allowed him to connect with its conscience, I think.

Sorry for being so obtuse, I just seem to have forgotten everything about it and would like to read it again. I also do believe I picked it up from a thread somewhere on this site.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds a bit like *[Norby's Other Secret](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0802765254)* (1984) by Janet and Isaac Asimov.

The Norby series is set of YA/Children's books about a boy (Jeff) and his rather goofy robot that has special abilities.  In *Norby's Other Secret*,

> Jeff is summoned to the large castle on the hill by the Mentor, a large four-armed robot. When he and Norby arrive at the castle, Jeff is confined by a misty force field, but Norby escapes through hyperspace. Jeff's mind is scanned by a computer until Norby can rescue him.
>
> <sub>[Amazon review](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486472442)</sub>

I believe Norby has to plug into the computer to talk with it to get it to release Jeff.

Comment: I edited out the part about leaving comments - I get your frustration, especially on story-IDs, but partial matches have value as well, especially a rather well redacted like this one :) Don't worry about commenting everywhere; you'll get there eventually, when you reach 50 rep - see the [privileges page](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) about the various stuff you will "unlock" along the way.